# differentiating an ode w.r.t one of the derivatives

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, euler-lagrange-equation

I am trying to solve some Lagrange mechanics functions and I have to differentiate a differential equation like $a q^2 + b q +c \dot{q} $ with respect to the derivative. Is it correct to simply treat $q$ as a constant during the differentiation like this:

$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{q}} ( a q^2 + b q +c \dot{q}) = c $

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes. But you should fresh up on the terminology. In the Euler-Lagrange equation $\frac{d}{dt}\frac{∂L}{∂\dot q}-\frac{∂L}{∂q}=0$, $L$ is not a differential equation but the Lagrange functional.

Comment: thank you very much! That makes sense to me.